# How to make a model and repository into one class of properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, repository

I'm currently working on a new mvc website with repositories. I always worked with oldschool sql and it's now time to move on.

So what i currently have is a repository with my databases and properties, but i also have a model with almost the same properties to validate all the fields before inserting the new values. Now i have two classes with almost the same properties. Is there a way to validate my properties in my repository?

So what i am currently doing in this example is filling up my model with the information of my repository so i can validate it later. But i just want to return only the repository, i am not sure if that's possible but i am pretty sure it's.

Example:

```
    public ActionResult Wijzig(int id)
    {
        // Generate view model
        var bundleModel = new Models.BundleGebruikersPasswordModel
        {
            WijzigGebruikersModel = new Models.WijzigGebruikersModel(),
            PasswordModel = new Models.PasswordModel()
        };

        // Get user repository
        var userRepository = new UsersRepository();

        // Get specific user
        var userInformation = userRepository.GetById(id);

        // Fill model fields
        bundleModel.WijzigGebruikersModel.GebruikersId = id;
        bundleModel.WijzigGebruikersModel.Voornaam = userInformation.Voornaam;
        bundleModel.WijzigGebruikersModel.Achternaam = userInformation.Achternaam;
        bundleModel.WijzigGebruikersModel.AdresToevoeging = userInformation.AdresToevoeging;
        bundleModel.WijzigGebruikersModel.BeveilingsAntwoord = userInformation.BeveilingsAntwoord;
        bundleModel.WijzigGebruikersModel.BeveilingsVraagId = userInformation.BeveilingsVraag;
        bundleModel.WijzigGebruikersModel.Email = userInformation.Email;
        bundleModel.WijzigGebruikersModel.Huisnummer = userInformation.Huisnummer;
        bundleModel.WijzigGebruikersModel.LandId = userInformation.Land;
        bundleModel.WijzigGebruikersModel.Woonplaats = userInformation.Woonplaats;
        bundleModel.WijzigGebruikersModel.Straat = userInformation.Straat;
        bundleModel.WijzigGebruikersModel.Postcode = userInformation.Postcode;
        bundleModel.WijzigGebruikersModel.LandenList = userRepository.GetLanden(userInformation.Land);
        bundleModel.WijzigGebruikersModel.BeveilingsVragenList = userRepository.GetBeveilingsVragen(userInformation.BeveilingsVraag);
        bundleModel.WijzigGebruikersModel.GroepenList = userRepository.GetGroepen(userInformation.GroepID);
        bundleModel.PasswordModel.GebruikersId = id;

        // Return model
        return View(bundleModel);
    }
```

Thanks in advance for helping me, always appreciate it!

Comment: You may want to look at NHibernate, I think that will do what you're trying to do. I can't really tell what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Not sure why i am being downvoted, i tried my best to explain as much as possible what i would like to do. Please explain to me what i did wrong or what you didn't understand.

Comment: @Jamie - I think the title you have on this post does not really translate to what is actually in the content of your post. Perhaps that might be a reason folks are downvoting this. As D4nC00per said in his post can't really tell what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @Gjohn Thanks for the feedback, i have changed the title so it matched the content of the question more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But i just want to return only the repository

Returning `userRepository` instead of `bundleModel` on the View might force you to write logic on a View (e.g. `userRepository.GetById((int)ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"])`)
**I suggest you not use this approach since it violates the main intention of MVC pattern - separation of concerns.**

> So what i am currently doing in this example is filling up my model with the information of my repository so i can validate it later. But i just want to return only the repository, i am not sure if that's possible but i am pretty sure it's.

1. **If you want to simplify creation of `bundleModel`** you can use [Automapper](http://automapper.org/).

   ```
   var bundleModel = new Models.BundleGebruikersPasswordModel
   {
       WijzigGebruikersModel = new Models.WijzigGebruikersModel() { GebruikersId = id },
       PasswordModel = Mapper.Map<User, Models.WijzigGebruikersModel>(userRepository.GetById(id))
   };
   ```

   or even

   ```
   var bundleModel = Mapper.Map<User, Models.BundleGebruikersPasswordModel>(userRepository.GetById(id));
   ```

   But you should read more about configuring Automapper.
2. **If you want to avoid usage of view models** `Models.WijzigGebruikersModel` and `Models.PasswordModel` you can use `User` entity ensted of them. **But I would not recommend this solution also since your View knows about your Domain Model in this case.**

   ```
   // Return model
   return View(userRepository.GetById(id));
   ```

There are several good links related to best practices in Asp.Net MVC

1. [12 ASP.NET MVC Best Practices](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/10/27/12-asp.net-mvc-best-practices.aspx)
2. [Best Practices for ASP.NET MVC](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aspnetue/archive/2010/09/17/second_2d00_post.aspx)
3. [Best MVC Practices](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.best-practices)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the first linked should help me a lot. (http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/10/25/asp.net-mvc-view-model-patterns.aspx)